# Cannot identify the source of uncoded element in oh-my-posh prompt

Tags: git, powershell, windows-terminal, posh-git

I'm using oh-my-posh v3 in Windows Terminal.

If I'm in a non-git directory, my prompt looks like this...
[image: Non-git prompt]

but, in a git-enabled directory it looks like this...
[image]

I've exported the theme's definition to json and, as you can see, I can't find anything that seems to be responsible for the first block in the prompt.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/main/themes/schema.json",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "alignment": "left",
      "segments": [
        {
          "background": "#c386f1",
          "foreground": "#ffffff",
          "leading_diamond": "",
          "style": "diamond",
          "trailing_diamond": "",
          "type": "session"
        },
        {
          "background": "#ff479c",
          "foreground": "#ffffff",
          "powerline_symbol": "",
          "properties": {
            "prefix": "  ",
            "style": "folder"
          },
          "style": "powerline",
          "type": "path"
        },
        {
          "background": "#fffb38",
          "foreground": "#193549",
          "powerline_symbol": "",
          "properties": {
            "display_stash_count": true,
            "display_upstream_icon": true
          },
          "style": "powerline",
          "type": "git"
        },
        {
          "background": "#f36943",
          "foreground": "#193549",
          "powerline_symbol": "",
          "properties": {
            "battery_icon": "",
            "charged_color": "#4caf50",
            "charging_color": "#40c4ff",
            "color_background": true,
            "discharging_color": "#ff5722",
            "postfix": " "
          },
          "style": "powerline",
          "type": "battery"
        },
        {
          "background": "#6CA35E",
          "foreground": "#ffffff",
          "powerline_symbol": "",
          "properties": {
            "prefix": "  "
          },
          "style": "powerline",
          "type": "node"
        },
        {
          "background": "#0077c2",
          "foreground": "#ffffff",
          "powerline_symbol": "",
          "properties": {
            "prefix": " ﲵ "
          },
          "style": "powerline",
          "type": "shell"
        },
        {
          "background": "#ffff66",
          "foreground": "#193549",
          "powerline_symbol": "",
          "style": "powerline",
          "type": "root"
        },
        {
          "background": "#2e9599",
          "foreground": "#ffffff",
          "leading_diamond": "",
          "properties": {
            "always_enabled": true,
            "color_background": true,
            "display_exit_code": false,
            "error_color": "#f1184c",
            "prefix": "<transparent></> "
          },
          "style": "diamond",
          "trailing_diamond": "",
          "type": "exit"
        }
      ],
      "type": "prompt"
    }
  ],
  "final_space": true
}
```

My $Profile looks like this...

```
Import-Module posh-git
Import-Module oh-my-posh
Import-Module -Name Terminal-Icons
Set-PoshPrompt -Theme jandedobbeleer
```

Can anyone suggest where this is coming from?

Comment: I took your profile and run it in my windows terminal and there's no git segment at the beginning, so I think json is okey.

Comment: Hmmm. Where _else_ could it be coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be simple; remove `Import-Module posh-git` from my $profile